# I'm unreasonably getting zero as an output and I can't figure out why

Tags: c

I'm a begginer programmer and I've been experimenting with this code but I can't figure out why it's giving me zero. I've checked for integer divison , and wrong place holders but I can't find any . I also believe I'm using the correct format for every function such as printf , scanf etc. can anyone hepl ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

    int main()
    {
        double theta , fr  , a, pi = 3.1459;
       
        printf("Enter the value of a \n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        theta = atan2(a,27.5);
        printf("%f",theta);
        fr = 1.67*pow(10,-6)*sin(theta);
        printf(" frequency = %f",fr);
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "believe I'm using the correct format " --> Not quite.  Enable all compiler warnings to see trouble with `double  a ... scanf("%f",&a);`.

Comment: If `fr` is zero then presumably one of the earlier muliplicands must be zero. Print them out individually or debug the code to see their value. Work backwards from there till you find something that explains the problem.

Comment: See [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) under *"Modifier Characters"*., you want a `double` right?

Comment: π is closer to 3.14159 than to 3.1459. And use `1.67e-6`, not `1.67*pow(10,-6)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct format specifiers for every data type. Your variables are doubles so you need to use `%lf` for scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to debug programs yourself. If you add one `printf` mode the problem becomes obvious:

```
        printf("Enter the value of a \n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("%f\n", a);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cj3zo6Yqn
It is prints zero `0`. So scanf did not scan properly.

Changing to

```
        scanf("%lf",&a);
```

Resolves the problem.
https://godbolt.org/z/jcjrYaG5j